# Random Winner Based on Percentage Weighting

Tags: c#

I have 3 variables and each one has their own percentage to win out of 99.99...%. (The 3 percentages don't act up to 100% perfectly)

When button1 is clicked, it will go through 100,000 simulations and afterwards it will output how many times each variable "won" in a MessageBox.

I would like some help optimizing my code. I feel like it's too clunky and maybe there's an easier way to complete the same task with far less lines.

```
private Random rand = new Random();

private int aWon = 0;
private int bWon = 0;
private int cWon = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // loop 100000 times for an accurate sample size output
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        // randomNumber == a random number between 0 and 0.9999999999999999
        double randomNumber = rand.NextDouble() * (0.9999999999999999 - 0) + 0;
        // a + b + c == 0.9999999999999999
        double a = 0.4917127071823204; // ~49% to win
        double b = 0.3922651933701657; // ~39% to win
        double c = 0.1160220994475138; // ~11% to win

        // if randomNumber is less than or equal to 0.9999999999999999
        // AND greater than 0.5082872928176795
        //
        // 0.9999999999999999   -   0.5082872928176795   =   0.4917127071823204 ( a's value )
        if (randomNumber <= a + b + c && randomNumber > b + c)
        {
            aWon += 1;
        }

        // if randomNumber is less than or equal to 0.5082872928176795
        // AND greater than 0.1160220994475138
        //
        // 0.5082872928176795   -   0.1160220994475138   =   0.3922651933701657 ( b's value )
        if (randomNumber <= b + c && randomNumber > c)
        {
            bWon += 1;
        }

        // if randomNumber is less than or equal to 0.1160220994475138
        //
        // 0.1160220994475138   -   0   =   0.1160220994475138 ( c's value )
        if (randomNumber <= c)
        {
            cWon += 1;
        }
    }

    // show how many times each variable won
    MessageBox.Show(aWon + "\n" + bWon + "\n" + cWon);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Doubles are only accurate to about 15 decimal places. You are trying to represent a difference from 1.0 of one part in ten to the 17.  Why are you trying to do this? It's not going to work, and even if it did, you'd only notice a difference after running several billion years worth of trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are always the same, so it makes sense to move them out of the loop. The same goes for sums of these variables, such as `a + b + c`, and `b + c`.

The conditions used to evaluate `randomNumber` can be simplified,
and it will be good to join them with `else if` to avoid unnecessarily repeated evaluations. Something like this:

```
double a = 0.4917127071823204; // ~49% to win
double b = 0.3922651933701657; // ~39% to win
double c = 0.1160220994475138; // ~11% to win
double min = 0;
double max = a + b +c;
double ab = a + b;

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    double randomNumber = rand.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;

    if (randomNumber <= a)
    {
        aWon += 1;
    }

    else if (randomNumber <= ab)
    {
        bWon += 1;
    }

    else
    {
        cWon += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done! This looks great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just take out all of the functional code from the button click handler and put it in some place where even other members can reach it, and then you just call it from there, something like this:

```
        public static int[] Calculate()
        {
            int aWon = 0;
            int bWon = 0;
            int cWon = 0;
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {

                // randomNumber == a random number between 0 and 0.9999999999999999
                double randomNumber = rand.NextDouble() * (0.9999999999999999 - 0) + 0;
                // a + b + c == 0.9999999999999999
                const double a = 0.4917127071823204; // ~49% to win
                const double b = 0.3922651933701657; // ~39% to win
                const double c = 0.1160220994475138; // ~11% to win

                // if randomNumber is less than or equal to 0.9999999999999999
                // AND greater than 0.5082872928176795
                //
                // 0.9999999999999999   -   0.5082872928176795   =   0.4917127071823204 ( a's value )
                if (randomNumber <= a + b + c && randomNumber > b + c)
                {
                    aWon += 1;
                }

                // if randomNumber is less than or equal to 0.5082872928176795
                // AND greater than 0.1160220994475138
                //
                // 0.5082872928176795   -   0.1160220994475138   =   0.3922651933701657 ( b's value )
                else if (randomNumber <= b + c && randomNumber > c)
                {
                    bWon += 1;
                }

                // if randomNumber is less than or equal to 0.1160220994475138
                //
                // 0.1160220994475138   -   0   =   0.1160220994475138 ( c's value )
                else 
                {
                    cWon += 1;
                }
            }
            return new int[] { aWon, bWon, cWon };
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] result = Calculate();
            MessageBox.Show(result[0] + "\n" + result[1] + "\n" + result[2]);
        }
```

Also, your random isnt that good, it can be made much simpler, and i also used const to the % of win for a,b and c since obviously they are constant values, changed the repetitive if statements. I'm not that good in math, but i'm also sure your comparisons in the if statements can be changed and made much faster and simpler in general.